# Is it ok to KILL this DELETE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran a query to delete around 4 million rows from my database. It ran for about 12 hours before my laptop lost the network connection. At that point, I decided to take a look at the status of the query in the database. I found that it was in the `suspended` state. Specifically:

```
 Start Time               SPID  Database    Executing SQL    Status     command    wait_type        wait_time   wait_resource   last_wait_type
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2018/08/15 11:28:39.490  115   RingClone   *see below       suspended  DELETE     PAGEIOLATCH_EX   41          5:1:1116111     PAGEIOLATCH_EX
```

*Here is the sql query in question:

```
DELETE FROM T_INDEXRAWDATA WHERE INDEXRAWDATAID IN (SELECT INDEXRAWDATAID FROM T_INDEX WHERE OWNERID='1486836020')
```

After reading this;

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87066/sql-query-in-suspended-state-causing-high-cpu-usage

I realize I probably should have broken this up into smaller pieces to delete them (or even delete them one-by-one). But now I just want to know if it is "safe" for me to `KILL` this query, as the answer in that post suggests. One thing the selected answer states is that "you may run into data consistency problems" if you `KILL` a query while it's executing. If it causes some issues with the data I am trying to delete, I'm not that concerned. However, I'm more concerned about this causing some issues with other data, or with the table structure itself.

Is it safe to `KILL` this query?

Comment: If that single delete fails, whether by `KILL` or network failure or client timeout, it will be rolled back to keep the database consistent... and that will take about 12 hours :/ BTW, queries go into suspended state all the time. Then they come out again. It's waiting on `PAGEIOLATCH_EX` which can be reduced with faster disks or more memory (... or yes... deleting in smaller batches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ran the `delete` from your laptop over the network and it lost connection with the server, you can either `kill` the spid or wait when it will disappear by itself. Depending on the `@@version` of your SQL Server instance, in particular how well it's patched, the latter might require instance restart.

Regarding the consistency issues, you seem to misunderstand it. It is possible only if you had multiple statements run in a single batch without being wrapped with a transaction. As I understand, you had a single statement; if that's the case, don't worry about consistency, SQL Server wouldn't have become what it is now if it would be so easy to corrupt its data.

I would have rewritten the query however, if `T_INDEX.INDEXRAWDATAID` column has NULLs then you can run into issues. It's better to rewrite it via `join`, also adding batch splitting:

```
while 1=1 begin

    DELETE top (10000) t
    FROM T_INDEXRAWDATA t
        inner join T_INDEX i on t.INDEXRAWDATAID = i.INDEXRAWDATAID
    WHERE i.OWNERID = '1486836020';

    if @@rowcount = 0
        break;

    checkpoint;
end;
```

It definitely will not be any slower, but it can boost performance, depending on your schema, data and the state of any indices the tables have.